# Docker DeviceMapper Driver not Freeing Space RHEL 7

Tags: docker, redhat-enterprise-linux, kubernetes, device-mapper

I searched around a bit a while back and found stuff about using loop device, which we are not, and using fstrim to free space. I ended up just rebuilding my kubernetes working nodes to clear the space back up last time and switching from XFS to EXT4 after reading some things about potential issues with XFS releasing space with thin provisioning. We appear to be creeping back up to the same point now, though, and I am wondering what is going on.

My suspicion is the device mapper is being used to create thin volumes and then they are being orphaned, but I can't see them using the dmsetup command. This problem seems to be unique to the kubernetes worker nodes, I guess it could be something with Rancher and Kubernetes and how it is interacting with Docker?

```
docker_host:~ # cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)
docker_host:~ # docker info
Containers: 101
 Running: 83
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 18
Images: 56
Server Version: 17.03.2-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: k8s_vol1-docker_thinpool
 Pool Blocksize: 131.1 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Data file:
 Metadata file:
 Data Space Used: 48.32 GB
 Data Space Total: 214.7 GB
 Data Space Available: 166.4 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 862.3 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.252 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 1.39 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 21.47 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-11-16)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.0 (Maipo)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 16
Total Memory: 62.76 GiB
Name: docker_host
ID: *******
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 ###.###.###.###:####
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

docker_host:~ # lvs
  LV                VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  docker_containers k8s_vol1 -wi-ao----  50.00g
  docker_thinpool   k8s_vol1 twi-aotz-- 200.00g             22.50  38.28
  kubelet           k8s_vol1 -wi-ao----  10.00g
  optlv             k8s_vol1 -wi-ao----  10.00g
  rook_ceph         k8s_vol1 -wi-ao---- 200.00g
  root              os       -wi-ao----  10.00g
  swap              os       -wi-ao----   2.00g
  tmp               os       -wi-ao----   2.00g
  var               os       -wi-ao----   5.00g
docker_host:~ # pvs
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda2  os       lvm2 a--    29.47g  10.47g
  /dev/sdb   k8s_vol1 lvm2 a--  1000.00g 527.80g
docker_host:~ # vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  k8s_vol1   1   5   0 wz--n- 1000.00g 527.80g
  os         1   4   0 wz--n-   29.47g  10.47g
docker_host:~ # dmsetup ls
docker-253:3-101498017-72bcd76347e26fed9b0332842d42dab557262ef56d6abefb6faff3247efa1cf8 (253:79)
docker-253:3-101498017-cb9540890830b416bbc03da01f68a446604b55682b3e5e82740eeb37a8e8fb24 (253:12)
docker-253:3-101498017-692db6edc24c878f9caa45c89c930120e6c0b3897f62e468aa1ba56482743a8f (253:95)
docker-253:3-101498017-c31f527f16b1d4126a0b18c22b54ec1121d83f3f3a13a38f218a8956b700202e (253:74)
docker-253:3-101498017-2ca06d5355e51a41695b3a407c141d540ce3eaebfaf79d55c39e7bf5b14ec0fd (253:88)
docker-253:3-101498017-1e91e539f9a112909e7439bca13629864a2d7f1797c3cc42944dc01a6ed07001 (253:39)
docker-253:3-101498017-b72394e1b06d75059d7696e41cb92e2904dfb68c66b4d44bb7e5710c9d078734 (253:27)
docker-253:3-101498017-3bb55da27654a22e832141e1ef8f943ac22b3f06f96315033a99529b43a1fd7e (253:90)
docker-253:3-101498017-a2e755e978eeda8788df96e95eb811e40f1e747aa08b9dbdd3bd9affcbf4765f (253:14)
os-tmp  (253:7)
docker-253:3-101498017-58aae6188dca08a773f7b0dd3c051ca315006054ae87a6864488750419183451 (253:59)
docker-253:3-101498017-7d23c8c042d3eca16b215cd90a244d931fa8c1f7c0d9f6354c8aba1442d185a9 (253:62)
docker-253:3-101498017-081c71e18b31c9bb8e92bba85e97768be3c9bbfc0d5fb9d0bdd0f9d5299278ef (253:76)
docker-253:3-101498017-57fe21d56db1e80144e67f29eea5d52eeb2140248f13ecdda24430f33a76b75f (253:68)
docker-253:3-101498017-9b4be0f839de894812e1918c7d46eecaff84f816d58ac17818b4b9069088081b (253:82)
docker-253:3-101498017-66c8b4df11fff26acb065b57fa1ead99cdbb91ca53af794b7d5f9fa93dc421ca (253:80)
docker-253:3-101498017-e8658773d4478b95145832dd4ce68ff8acb90e0128cf1a4cd1592b3d10b56c14 (253:40)
docker-253:3-101498017-83d87da21d2cc6717b3b9bf64f85552af572363cb75eaf6aa8a5443dc1815ede (253:16)
docker-253:3-101498017-d6f8df43759458ef8c66ee84a618e98d6b1e3f3664e69134136df5fa41b0f980 (253:46)
docker-253:3-101498017-861e4d8fd60e438a93589bf114df45fde0dde59e805287b477aef8fd30335ad0 (253:73)
docker-253:3-101498017-15a7b53ae901d70b709733315f70b3e7b77d48177bf719799436877b04661533 (253:72)
docker-253:3-101498017-82d44c0769935c8e64d28806b525f4daf2c9011fbb8566b10c7c357dee88b295 (253:70)
docker-253:3-101498017-cde50281f6d9a07d8d227d97ab1621c00dea5467dfca97f7cea8e668d6cd4195 (253:45)
docker-253:3-101498017-dc85b9e7171b469ba9f32e8a1f91671a03e2933606aa1b53edeadc3de13d4972 (253:61)
docker-253:3-101498017-7688a3352e7b0caa35b55a83c8f62fd1edb5b527bbce25bfa6374763bcc789f2 (253:60)
docker-253:3-101498017-0334a53c8f4afd225a961ca5e001cd0daed7d549027963e6b4af3601773315e6 (253:35)
docker-253:3-101498017-9a5f122b66aa832856a6cf9714517ccd2d5862fb29e71ce72af4c365f27a1520 (253:19)
docker-253:3-101498017-4a4e61a6cb0c02b3a918af44b98b554252d45cea5651acba3ec2f4e2d7d05cf0 (253:83)
docker-253:3-101498017-2d847821dc876c1cf9339e006f34562fdae9f4f5dae0219476045eada99c1b01 (253:15)
docker-253:3-101498017-c7f082591d74f0a1b2ded0e9c57ce5a76c3a92a2f119e63018b9d44aa5c5fb94 (253:65)
docker-253:3-101498017-d053d6aca55c7498de05048e17876f4081725e7c58a425950f465b6ec44702df (253:29)
os-var  (253:8)
docker-253:3-101498017-e0d6285982adca5d02f380a8d34793cfee94da06543e751e6e65211a055291b4 (253:85)
docker-253:3-101498017-280657ed58b3c2b6ad2985cf810f78f0a5a1224e194357912176c0140de26701 (253:23)
k8s_vol1-optlv  (253:2)
docker-253:3-101498017-94bf39e488c4de0ceb0547a49cbecc496ab7660113dafe3b0fd78bd7cb2aee51 (253:43)
docker-253:3-101498017-b16d5d13faec6ace9dee33ee736a720b265273d07514575f3e8c1815e3351035 (253:38)
docker-253:3-101498017-b9b8e8346860c24c9629241dd586e330c1948432a54f8d5f2efd114329be2dfd (253:57)
docker-253:3-101498017-a96d4b4b9aac6459b36ca93bd71092f60fc72a204fc13bd83c3efdd4b46e6f52 (253:17)
k8s_vol1-docker_containers      (253:3)
docker-253:3-101498017-b8baaa0a194a40ffd4b165a1a381b84706cb6a60fd46d80306efec146e431f95 (253:77)
docker-253:3-101498017-c055e9a480a884f00333dd6a2c335da3409aefcc807ee52e6bf8f78362095bc9 (253:26)
k8s_vol1-rook_ceph      (253:10)
docker-253:3-101498017-9ce68f7c91a3ed26264668f3de3ae558975a92b9f8d6233a82c7bff784d21ccb (253:49)
docker-253:3-101498017-c6d44daa361bc0439bba8346b193b04c4c8252e600ed722de7b7aa8cdc0b28d2 (253:63)
docker-253:3-101498017-5ce0e9df887903b61491b9ca51b49ebdd1cfa790ae010606d6098049683a86f3 (253:71)
docker-253:3-101498017-01e0ff2289f9d72c93d6cf94187d7682bec99e3a02e4cdc4916f6d1d4cbdf5dc (253:41)
docker-253:3-101498017-8a552cf69c2d25746795a0e5a3e9535c0c926246c865052252be88bd23980490 (253:92)
docker-253:3-101498017-9c74c5623eb36c4ffa7ced7ceb838ba227cd5b434a9ae06e3131a9c90c7a238c (253:22)
docker-253:3-101498017-19f400317e661c19ddd8ee6a6d7f25eeb48e54c67ed8c31667babbff70486899 (253:67)
docker-253:3-101498017-c7e0ad7332c64312fb79d4a3aebead2c842d5606f90caef786ba0ca6fd61d669 (253:54)
docker-253:3-101498017-aea189e064aa1820ce56a3155d5c949dca68008d22582c533b357654329d8a31 (253:66)
docker-253:3-101498017-26273229d473b48898bc0426694ade5010f36ddab8948529fbbdc7f5acc5841d (253:36)
docker-253:3-101498017-1cee6b102ce6671c0a44e1350c562208e1af3ea3e2b7d58b6967dffca32265d2 (253:37)
docker-253:3-101498017-f56c67d4d326547eb35a6c8e9170f74d23d137371312e53c78fef27abe6aba61 (253:24)
docker-253:3-101498017-9d3379bcb8edbb38e0db85fb8a54e46db953c2fa6fc5ebca18e2a4c3f6d47e84 (253:47)
docker-253:3-101498017-456b66ba8079c962fb9c6239d33440984d86a02ea6bfdc6718597a70307b529f (253:32)
k8s_vol1-docker_thinpool_tdata  (253:6)
docker-253:3-101498017-5aec78cb52a7e922839edcb7b6307a5f2d8d1847fc66061fd0c3a84cc2330e0e (253:48)
os-swap (253:0)
docker-253:3-101498017-f12784005d2ba8707dfcbb8424921ad2721698079253a3121289dd39689de282 (253:87)
docker-253:3-101498017-c0663ce2cafe4a458da70bbc96b5068c8f62989a4e53f289874df2f724057e81 (253:69)
docker-253:3-101498017-7cf9e87a2f613f0c7d7ca8c827986091e8b8c8132c7f1326a6f3d30b385d1d17 (253:33)
os-root (253:1)
docker-253:3-101498017-54df327f48ba863ffd70b1c249aa7da4d913fa317af99af971a63439e8efe139 (253:13)
docker-253:3-101498017-458803691c98537e1c92371a1fa956cf968f791f2bf51bff7678595c5160ba4f (253:64)
docker-253:3-101498017-d07e3bfe5c48623aceb7625c9e2d66ddfe523a06c303801ab4c29f6c33c68cdd (253:50)
docker-253:3-101498017-d9e37c4a49eba4d82e22dd07f6317d3d5714037f19e2aa3f15ab86c0162c8ed2 (253:21)
k8s_vol1-docker_thinpool_tmeta  (253:5)
k8s_vol1-docker_thinpool        (253:9)
docker-253:3-101498017-3c8c62d635216ac3ff6421ccb8d4dc835f399a08ec6b660b3c8edbd5503e2903 (253:42)
k8s_vol1-kubelet        (253:4)
docker-253:3-101498017-2d05d9275ecf718697c59aba19f67a3347fe4395dc37d89dd323d2889652d7ed (253:58)
docker-253:3-101498017-cb5813d7f1064e9b26fec5d91e1665205927769841df552bf1b72e65320d22ff (253:55)
docker-253:3-101498017-f697572e0551ec13f1c09d5e7a6e163b861ee08251a7e4d4e42fd4c589e418b2 (253:78)
docker-253:3-101498017-a61b78adab88a851dc75bb73daa289b8127d608e8f934b75f7689b2bac3924de (253:31)
docker-253:3-101498017-e36d383f3d2aa4e02c57374bbac54c9b998a22d2ac2cfc4bbbe2092b914cc05f (253:11)
docker-253:3-101498017-87f74f834c7eb9aed8b1d781638a375107237e9e0d32ad5ad1e22297a1ac6c4c (253:25)
docker-253:3-101498017-2fdea3314ebf45424145f8c67458de28ffb8e512919c2d4429a14be9a37e64f5 (253:18)
docker-253:3-101498017-cbf7504c9b084a6942c28c4944669b0e7d549cad9fb9b79b8d12e1a87c030a35 (253:75)
docker-253:3-101498017-e88e9db7e1fd3706918f7269ee38f62b7a9a5b12318991dbd19299cf2630d736 (253:89)
docker-253:3-101498017-a09c944b5dadb6aff47b31099cc0884af9996d0526403d9bbc8c86823051aaff (253:51)
docker-253:3-101498017-3c7a5d24808362d90d1b22074235943378b4488122733453e369e4509e5ee2a2 (253:20)
docker-253:3-101498017-4e1f157bba6ead05baa86d72fb8f7e90705090db89196cb84d1dab916c369a47 (253:84)
docker-253:3-101498017-1f7cb658dbbb2ab9635eb2dd6c29219fb84a659d60bb5fef6fdee7977b658cd7 (253:30)
docker-253:3-101498017-7b5a238eebb203422ab5daa6a8706950337124e2ce0bcc622b613231ed03f224 (253:34)
docker-253:3-101498017-8e564cde63bdb70ea017b2cef69b68cfa10e22ddea0451229fd1bb7ab67d05fa (253:28)
docker-253:3-101498017-7d0a3e631d18fc56e7d80b3132786c46cd2cf4efc24ea6ff367e17e208474da2 (253:81)
docker-253:3-101498017-3c897c44a0b7287dc91afcdf4e913dec6084e8816b7a0c2b1dd3bc832cf116f7 (253:94)
docker-253:3-101498017-7e8da0104cc1b0434c6d95cfdbb68a89f2c7a9ec8502467613bf1e61052de6f5 (253:56)
docker-253:3-101498017-9b3b2b78d0ed36d8c382520cb983f179777e936212e90b87edcec88a8adf91b9 (253:52)
docker-253:3-101498017-661cacf156942f9ffe9018140ceca192df12d33628b9d483a9a0439fe2e2402d (253:86)
docker-253:3-101498017-547a6a68db282fabcbf4377151b4d3df076a4b8497012d36e217187fcd6eaf57 (253:53)
docker-253:3-101498017-0e536306352fea1c007f71e8e87703ab79eefcd1ea8330b7b8e9f4ce6fc5d0ce (253:44)
docker_host:~ # df | grep dm- | wc -l
83
docker_host:~ # dmsetup ls | wc -l
94
docker_host:~ # dmsetup ls | grep docker | wc -l
87
docker_host:~ #  df | grep dm-
/dev/dm-12                                                10190100    1129120   8520308  12% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/cb9540890830b416bbc03da01f68a446604b55682b3e5e82740eeb37a8e8fb24
/dev/dm-13                                                10190100    1129448   8519980  12% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/54df327f48ba863ffd70b1c249aa7da4d913fa317af99af971a63439e8efe139
/dev/dm-14                                                10190100     165092   9484336   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/a2e755e978eeda8788df96e95eb811e40f1e747aa08b9dbdd3bd9affcbf4765f
/dev/dm-15                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2d847821dc876c1cf9339e006f34562fdae9f4f5dae0219476045eada99c1b01
/dev/dm-17                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/a96d4b4b9aac6459b36ca93bd71092f60fc72a204fc13bd83c3efdd4b46e6f52
/dev/dm-18                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2fdea3314ebf45424145f8c67458de28ffb8e512919c2d4429a14be9a37e64f5
/dev/dm-19                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/9a5f122b66aa832856a6cf9714517ccd2d5862fb29e71ce72af4c365f27a1520
/dev/dm-20                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/3c7a5d24808362d90d1b22074235943378b4488122733453e369e4509e5ee2a2
/dev/dm-21                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/d9e37c4a49eba4d82e22dd07f6317d3d5714037f19e2aa3f15ab86c0162c8ed2
/dev/dm-24                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/f56c67d4d326547eb35a6c8e9170f74d23d137371312e53c78fef27abe6aba61
/dev/dm-22                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/9c74c5623eb36c4ffa7ced7ceb838ba227cd5b434a9ae06e3131a9c90c7a238c
/dev/dm-25                                                10190100     319768   9329660   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/87f74f834c7eb9aed8b1d781638a375107237e9e0d32ad5ad1e22297a1ac6c4c
/dev/dm-23                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/280657ed58b3c2b6ad2985cf810f78f0a5a1224e194357912176c0140de26701
/dev/dm-27                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/b72394e1b06d75059d7696e41cb92e2904dfb68c66b4d44bb7e5710c9d078734
/dev/dm-29                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/d053d6aca55c7498de05048e17876f4081725e7c58a425950f465b6ec44702df
/dev/dm-28                                                10190100     143968   9505460   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/8e564cde63bdb70ea017b2cef69b68cfa10e22ddea0451229fd1bb7ab67d05fa
/dev/dm-26                                                10190100     281632   9367796   3% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c055e9a480a884f00333dd6a2c335da3409aefcc807ee52e6bf8f78362095bc9
/dev/dm-11                                                10190100     632460   9016968   7% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/e36d383f3d2aa4e02c57374bbac54c9b998a22d2ac2cfc4bbbe2092b914cc05f
/dev/dm-16                                                10190100      64968   9584460   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/83d87da21d2cc6717b3b9bf64f85552af572363cb75eaf6aa8a5443dc1815ede
/dev/dm-30                                                10190100      61484   9587944   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/1f7cb658dbbb2ab9635eb2dd6c29219fb84a659d60bb5fef6fdee7977b658cd7
/dev/dm-31                                                10190100     546804   9102624   6% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/a61b78adab88a851dc75bb73daa289b8127d608e8f934b75f7689b2bac3924de
/dev/dm-33                                                10190100     319768   9329660   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/7cf9e87a2f613f0c7d7ca8c827986091e8b8c8132c7f1326a6f3d30b385d1d17
/dev/dm-34                                                10190100     104316   9545112   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/7b5a238eebb203422ab5daa6a8706950337124e2ce0bcc622b613231ed03f224
/dev/dm-35                                                10190100      82192   9567236   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/0334a53c8f4afd225a961ca5e001cd0daed7d549027963e6b4af3601773315e6
/dev/dm-38                                                10190100     536900   9112528   6% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/b16d5d13faec6ace9dee33ee736a720b265273d07514575f3e8c1815e3351035
/dev/dm-37                                                10190100     536900   9112528   6% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/1cee6b102ce6671c0a44e1350c562208e1af3ea3e2b7d58b6967dffca32265d2
/dev/dm-32                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/456b66ba8079c962fb9c6239d33440984d86a02ea6bfdc6718597a70307b529f
/dev/dm-36                                                10190100     632460   9016968   7% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/26273229d473b48898bc0426694ade5010f36ddab8948529fbbdc7f5acc5841d
/dev/dm-41                                                10190100     536904   9112524   6% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/01e0ff2289f9d72c93d6cf94187d7682bec99e3a02e4cdc4916f6d1d4cbdf5dc
/dev/dm-40                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/e8658773d4478b95145832dd4ce68ff8acb90e0128cf1a4cd1592b3d10b56c14
/dev/dm-42                                                10190100     536908   9112520   6% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/3c8c62d635216ac3ff6421ccb8d4dc835f399a08ec6b660b3c8edbd5503e2903
/dev/dm-39                                                10190100      89256   9560172   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/1e91e539f9a112909e7439bca13629864a2d7f1797c3cc42944dc01a6ed07001
/dev/dm-44                                                10190100      89256   9560172   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/0e536306352fea1c007f71e8e87703ab79eefcd1ea8330b7b8e9f4ce6fc5d0ce
/dev/dm-43                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/94bf39e488c4de0ceb0547a49cbecc496ab7660113dafe3b0fd78bd7cb2aee51
/dev/dm-46                                                10190100     141136   9508292   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/d6f8df43759458ef8c66ee84a618e98d6b1e3f3664e69134136df5fa41b0f980
/dev/dm-55                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/cb5813d7f1064e9b26fec5d91e1665205927769841df552bf1b72e65320d22ff
/dev/dm-56                                                10190100      85836   9563592   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/7e8da0104cc1b0434c6d95cfdbb68a89f2c7a9ec8502467613bf1e61052de6f5
/dev/dm-57                                                10190100      76872   9572556   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/b9b8e8346860c24c9629241dd586e330c1948432a54f8d5f2efd114329be2dfd
/dev/dm-54                                                10190100      78100   9571328   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c7e0ad7332c64312fb79d4a3aebead2c842d5606f90caef786ba0ca6fd61d669
/dev/dm-53                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/547a6a68db282fabcbf4377151b4d3df076a4b8497012d36e217187fcd6eaf57
/dev/dm-52                                                10190100     287272   9362156   3% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/9b3b2b78d0ed36d8c382520cb983f179777e936212e90b87edcec88a8adf91b9
/dev/dm-50                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/d07e3bfe5c48623aceb7625c9e2d66ddfe523a06c303801ab4c29f6c33c68cdd
/dev/dm-51                                                10190100    1019208   8630220  11% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/a09c944b5dadb6aff47b31099cc0884af9996d0526403d9bbc8c86823051aaff
/dev/dm-58                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2d05d9275ecf718697c59aba19f67a3347fe4395dc37d89dd323d2889652d7ed
/dev/dm-59                                                10190100     177592   9471836   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/58aae6188dca08a773f7b0dd3c051ca315006054ae87a6864488750419183451
/dev/dm-60                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/7688a3352e7b0caa35b55a83c8f62fd1edb5b527bbce25bfa6374763bcc789f2
/dev/dm-61                                                10190100      73788   9575640   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/dc85b9e7171b469ba9f32e8a1f91671a03e2933606aa1b53edeadc3de13d4972
/dev/dm-63                                                10190100     141160   9508268   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c6d44daa361bc0439bba8346b193b04c4c8252e600ed722de7b7aa8cdc0b28d2
/dev/dm-68                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/57fe21d56db1e80144e67f29eea5d52eeb2140248f13ecdda24430f33a76b75f
/dev/dm-69                                                10190100     598648   9050780   7% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c0663ce2cafe4a458da70bbc96b5068c8f62989a4e53f289874df2f724057e81
/dev/dm-45                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/cde50281f6d9a07d8d227d97ab1621c00dea5467dfca97f7cea8e668d6cd4195
/dev/dm-48                                                10190100     205664   9443764   3% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/5aec78cb52a7e922839edcb7b6307a5f2d8d1847fc66061fd0c3a84cc2330e0e
/dev/dm-67                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/19f400317e661c19ddd8ee6a6d7f25eeb48e54c67ed8c31667babbff70486899
/dev/dm-74                                                10190100     601884   9047544   7% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c31f527f16b1d4126a0b18c22b54ec1121d83f3f3a13a38f218a8956b700202e
/dev/dm-64                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/458803691c98537e1c92371a1fa956cf968f791f2bf51bff7678595c5160ba4f
/dev/dm-65                                                10190100     954536   8694892  10% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c7f082591d74f0a1b2ded0e9c57ce5a76c3a92a2f119e63018b9d44aa5c5fb94
/dev/dm-75                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/cbf7504c9b084a6942c28c4944669b0e7d549cad9fb9b79b8d12e1a87c030a35
/dev/dm-76                                                10190100     439296   9210132   5% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/081c71e18b31c9bb8e92bba85e97768be3c9bbfc0d5fb9d0bdd0f9d5299278ef
/dev/dm-66                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/aea189e064aa1820ce56a3155d5c949dca68008d22582c533b357654329d8a31
/dev/dm-62                                                10190100     386920   9262508   5% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/7d23c8c042d3eca16b215cd90a244d931fa8c1f7c0d9f6354c8aba1442d185a9
/dev/dm-47                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/9d3379bcb8edbb38e0db85fb8a54e46db953c2fa6fc5ebca18e2a4c3f6d47e84
/dev/dm-49                                                10190100     681736   8967692   8% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/9ce68f7c91a3ed26264668f3de3ae558975a92b9f8d6233a82c7bff784d21ccb
/dev/dm-94                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/3c897c44a0b7287dc91afcdf4e913dec6084e8816b7a0c2b1dd3bc832cf116f7
/dev/dm-95                                                10190100     112708   9536720   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/692db6edc24c878f9caa45c89c930120e6c0b3897f62e468aa1ba56482743a8f
/dev/dm-70                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/82d44c0769935c8e64d28806b525f4daf2c9011fbb8566b10c7c357dee88b295
/dev/dm-72                                                10190100     430968   9218460   5% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/15a7b53ae901d70b709733315f70b3e7b77d48177bf719799436877b04661533
/dev/dm-79                                                10190100     319764   9329664   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/72bcd76347e26fed9b0332842d42dab557262ef56d6abefb6faff3247efa1cf8
/dev/dm-78                                                10190100     319764   9329664   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/f697572e0551ec13f1c09d5e7a6e163b861ee08251a7e4d4e42fd4c589e418b2
/dev/dm-77                                                10190100     319764   9329664   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/b8baaa0a194a40ffd4b165a1a381b84706cb6a60fd46d80306efec146e431f95
/dev/dm-73                                                10190100     319764   9329664   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/861e4d8fd60e438a93589bf114df45fde0dde59e805287b477aef8fd30335ad0
/dev/dm-71                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/5ce0e9df887903b61491b9ca51b49ebdd1cfa790ae010606d6098049683a86f3
/dev/dm-80                                                10190100     879836   8769592  10% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/66c8b4df11fff26acb065b57fa1ead99cdbb91ca53af794b7d5f9fa93dc421ca
/dev/dm-86                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/661cacf156942f9ffe9018140ceca192df12d33628b9d483a9a0439fe2e2402d
/dev/dm-89                                                10190100     285304   9364124   3% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/e88e9db7e1fd3706918f7269ee38f62b7a9a5b12318991dbd19299cf2630d736
/dev/dm-84                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/4e1f157bba6ead05baa86d72fb8f7e90705090db89196cb84d1dab916c369a47
/dev/dm-85                                                10190100    1019240   8630188  11% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/e0d6285982adca5d02f380a8d34793cfee94da06543e751e6e65211a055291b4
/dev/dm-81                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/7d0a3e631d18fc56e7d80b3132786c46cd2cf4efc24ea6ff367e17e208474da2
/dev/dm-82                                                10190100     523004   9126424   6% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/9b4be0f839de894812e1918c7d46eecaff84f816d58ac17818b4b9069088081b
/dev/dm-83                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/4a4e61a6cb0c02b3a918af44b98b554252d45cea5651acba3ec2f4e2d7d05cf0
/dev/dm-87                                                10190100    1329112   8320316  14% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/f12784005d2ba8707dfcbb8424921ad2721698079253a3121289dd39689de282
/dev/dm-88                                                10190100      37648   9611780   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2ca06d5355e51a41695b3a407c141d540ce3eaebfaf79d55c39e7bf5b14ec0fd
/dev/dm-90                                                10190100     417500   9231928   5% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/3bb55da27654a22e832141e1ef8f943ac22b3f06f96315033a99529b43a1fd7e
/dev/dm-92                                                10190100     319764   9329664   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/8a552cf69c2d25746795a0e5a3e9535c0c926246c865052252be88bd23980490
docker_host:~ # total=0; for s in `df | grep dm- | awk '{print $3}'`; do total=$(expr $total + $s); done; echo $(expr $total / 1024)
21255
docker_host:~ # docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              43                  41                  11.58 GB            450.3 MB (3%)
Containers          101                 83                  1.665 GB            83 B (0%)
Local Volumes       7                   7                   124.9 MB            0 B (0%)
docker_host:~ # cat /etc/docker/
daemon.json  key.json
docker_host:~ # cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "storage-driver": "devicemapper",
  "storage-opts": [
    "dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/k8s_vol1-docker_thinpool",
    "dm.use_deferred_removal=true",
    "dm.use_deferred_deletion=true",
    "dm.fs=ext4"
  ],
  "insecure-registries": ["###.###.###.###:####"]
}
```